# Fast default ordering for POD class in C++

Tags: c++, stl, containers, comparison-operators

Say I have some POD `struct Foo` in C++ which I want to put into an ordered container like `set<Foo>` . I do not care about which ordering is used, only that it be consistent and fast. What is the best way to do this?

More concretely, say I am on a 64-bit machine with `sizeof(long)==8`. Say the class is:

```
 struct Foo{
  long key; //8 bytes : 8 total
  int fum;  // 4 bytes : 12 total
  short n;  // 2 bytes : 14 total
  short n[3];  //6 bytes : 20 total
  char bar[5];  // 5 bytes : 25 total
  char name[23]; //22 bytes : 47 total
  char padding[1]; // 1 byte : 48 total 
 }
```

the `padding` field is just to make sure the size is multiple of 8.

Note that `sizeof(Foo)` is 48 so its contents can be represented in 6 `unsigned long`s, which is obviously the best way to do comparisons, rather than walking through each field.

Can the compiler do this for me automatically? Or do I have to either define a `union` with a field `unsigned long data[8]`, or cast a `Foo *` to `unsigned long *` in my `operator<` method for `Foo`?

Note that if there is no padding field, then one must generate 5 `unsigned long` comparisons, followed by comparisons of a `long`, a `short`, and a `char` comparison. This whole thing is kind of messy.

This issue must come up all the time, so I am guessing there is some best/best way to handle it.

Comment: Are you fixed on `std::set`? Maybe `std::unordered_set` in combination with a hash function may a good alternative (if you only use it for fast lookup, and don't need the order).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to compare using the struct actual value, it's best to define an `operator<` that has a bit more logic and gives some kind of logical ordering between the fields.

If you just want the objects sortable for fast access, you can just hold the pointes. Those are just numbers, and are sortable.

If you want to use the actual struct data, but don't care about any kind of ordering between the members, you can just use **[memcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcmp/)** with `sizeof(Foo)`.

Comment: I think I'd use sizeof(Foo) - sizeof(padding) given there's no real guarantee that the padding would be the same for two otherwise identical members

Comment: As I said in sentence 2 of my question, I only care about the order properties mentioned. The pointer idea is inapplicable in this context. Obviously if I had pointers to canonical objects I wouldn't need the comparator at all; one reason for the container is to get such pointers. memcmp has the right signature but (haven't timed it) it seems like it would be too slow. It deals with more complex semantics and is a runtime function.

Comment: i doubt you'd get a lot faster than memcmp. it doesn't deal with any semantics at all.

Comment: OK I'll time it at some point. Thanks for the pointer (so to speak).

Comment: My concern here is say this memcmp code, https://code.google.com/p/pic30/source/browse/branches/v3_24/gcc-4.0.3/gcc/config/memcmp.c?r=20 . It just uses a byte-by-byte comparison rather than using unsigned longs, for instance. I am using libc++ with clang++ and it is not exactly a paragon of efficiency in my experience. But like I said, I will test it.

Comment: Just to be clear again, find() into set<Foo> would be done 100s of millions of times in the program and, in the past, have been a good portion of the time (the container itself holds millions of Foos).

Comment: @kdog If you're searching for a structure millions of times, just a change of the container would be a great improvement. std::map has a logarithmic O(logn) complexity for search and add, and unordered_map  has an O(1) complexity for find and add. (it uses a hash table for storing the items)

Comment: @kdog you won't find a faster form of compare than the memcmp (unless you write it in assembly with vectoric intrinsics). Most compilers implement memcpy and memcmp with intrinsics anyway, so they use the CPU architecture to use vectoric registers (which could be more than 128 bits at a time in some CPUs). Just a list of the methods microsoft implements with intrinsics: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzkfha43.aspx

Comment: OK thanks. This discussion has been very helpful. By the way, Yochai, I tested unorder versus ordered in my app (in a different key class though) and didn't find a significant time difference. O(1) is not necessarily faster than O(log n) for any particular hash table size, after all. I'm using libc++ and clang, which might be very different from vc++ of course.

Comment: @kdog It depends on the size of the database. There's always a constant there... It's O(logn) + C and O(1) + D . The constant is the overhead of the actual functions (like hashing the object in a hash map). So it depends on the size of **n**, in a big enough n (usually over a 1000 or so, depends on the optimization flags) it will be noticeably faster.